# Why constructors can't return a value other than object even if it is explicitly instructed to do so?

Tags: php, constructor

I noticed that constructors in PHP classes cannot return a value other than objects when implicitly called from outside of the class:

```
class A
{
function __construct ()
{
   return FALSE;
}

function aFunctionInside ()
{
 $aVar = $this->__construct ();
 echo gettype($aVar); 
}
}

$A = new A;
$A->aFunctionInside (); // boolean
echo gettype ($A); //object
```

Is this behavior helpful in any case?

Comment: Logically, you get the instance itself as the "returned value", so how (and why) would you expect anything else to be returned? And why should you want to call the constructor in any other circumstance?

Comment: Unclear exactly what you're talking about.... If you need to instantiate multiple objects, one for each $_POST, then use a collection object, instantiate that, and let that instantiate objects for each individual $_POST var

Comment: @MarkBaker Sorry, I typed it incorrectly. I was thinking of a case where I am retrieving form data via POST, and need to count how many fields were filled in the form. If I wanted to do all the input sanitization inside the constructor, then I have to count it, escape special chars, all inside constructor and during the sanitization process, if something is wrong with the input, I may wish to flag that by returning false from the constructor. I know that constructor is not the right place to do such kind of things, so I am never going to do that. Just an example.

Comment: Logically, you might throw an Exception instead of trying to return a false; but you shouldn't be putting too much logic inside a constructor

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes, I totally agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A constructor is implicitly called when an object is created (with `new`). However, its return value is not used in that case, and has nothing to do with the object that is being created.

It is not the constructor that *creates* the object, because even without one, an object would be created anyway. What's more, when the constructor runs, the object is already there.

No return value is expected from a constructor. According to [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) it has no return type:

> **Constructor**
>
> ```
> void __construct ([ mixed $args = "" [, $... ]] )
> ```

You are of course free to return something and use that when you call that function explicitly, as with any other function, but don't expect that call to create another instantiation of your class. For that you need to use the `new` syntax.

The return value plays no role when it is called implicitly during object creation: the return value is ignored in that case.